# VS2010 nested msi installers

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-2010, deployment, installation

In my VS2010 install project I want my installer to start other msi installers, how do i do that? E.g. I have 3 .msi files that i want to be bundled with the msi and start automatically.

Comment: You'll have more flexibility using other installation packagers. I highly recommend [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do in Visual Studio is to use custom prerequisites:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77z6b8tz(VS.80).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429(VS.80).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx

After generating the package manifests, you can add all these files (including the package) in a separate folder in the Visual Studio prerequisites folder, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages
```

You can then select the prerequisite in your setup project property page.

Other setup authoring tools support adding packages as features inside your main installer.